# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when starting Flutter project

Tags: java, android, flutter

everyone I'm working on Flutter project but when I want to run my application I faced this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:xxxxxxxx'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)

I have tried multiple solutions like:

- changing the gradle.properties file to:

  - gradle.properties.org.gradle.jvmargs=-xmx4608m 
    android.enableR8=true 
    android.useAndroidX=true 
    android.enableJetifier=true
- Restarting my Pc
- Checking that I have enougth memory in my Pc and My phone
- Raising the minSdkVersion to 30

but it seems not to help too much.

Comment: Goto file : gradle.properties add this line :  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
Then flutter clean and flutter pub get and re run app

Comment: @HardikMehta, I have post my gradle.properties in my qst and the value of jvmargs=-Xmx4608m but not help

Comment: clear your space in your mobile

Comment: there is more then 50Gb of free space.

Comment: In my case, just `rerunning the app` solved this issue.

Comment: Try restarting your computer. Restarting it worked me.